# Xcode invalid top level type in JSON write

Tags: json, swift

Code:

```
    apiError(ios_service.GGAPIErrorMessage(json: {
        "register" : {
          "data" : {
            "fields" : [
             {
                "name" : "token",
                "value" : "zlS4OJxoskpvpXfdD9bE8zwjLjitqE"
             }],
             "params" : []
          },
        }
    }



do {
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: error, options: .prettyPrinted)
    print("jsonObject:\(jsonObject)")
} catch let error {
    print("error:\(error)")
}
```

Exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write

I need to handle error response from server. I shared my JSON parsing code.

Comment: remove comma after closing braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You JSON format is wrong. Please try below JSON:

```
{
    "register": {
        "data": {
            "fields": [{
                "name": "token",
                "value": "zlS4OJxoskpvpXfdD9bE8zwjLjitqE"
            }],
            "params": []
        }
    }
}
```

Remove extra comma from your JSON:

[image]

Comment: you know how to handle apiError(ios_service.GGAPIErrorMessage(json:  ?

Comment: `apiError(ios_service.GGAPIErrorMessage(json:` is internal method of your code. Error your are getting because of missing comma in your JSON. Did you make that change in JSON?